# How to prevent a long paragraph from breaking your CSS grid [template areas]

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to put together an absolutely simple layout, and it looks like I'm being thwarted by a p tag that is stretching the container beyond the grid layout, instead of expected behavior (wrapping).

Here's some basic code:

HTML:

```
<div class="top-level-wrapper">
  <header>I am a header!</header>
  <main>
    <h3>Some page title</h3>
    <p>
      Some text.
    </p>
  </main>
  <footer>I am a footer!</footer>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Layout stuff. */
header {grid-area: h;}
footer {grid-area: f;}
main {grid-area:m;}
.top-level-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "h h h h h"
    ". m m m ."
    "f f f f f";
}
```

My understanding is, this grid template area is basically saying, "There are 5 equal fractional units per row, and main shalt taketh the middle three at ALL times.

However, what ACTUALLY happens is, if that "some text" is lengthened, the template just breaks.

- Example 1 - Expected look: https://jsfiddle.net/r6j35vz3/1/
- Example 2 - Broken: https://jsfiddle.net/r6j35vz3/2/

How do I configure the grid to actually do the right thing regardless of how its contents might want to behave by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [**`grid-template-areas`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas) to build your grid. That lays out the columns and rows.

However, without [**`grid-template-columns`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) to define the width of each column, they will default to `auto` (i.e., content length). The first and last columns in the second row have no content, so they simply collapse. The three middle columns then consume all space in the row.

You need to use `grid-template-columns` to get the behavior you want. If you set each column to `1fr`, the row will be divided into five equal-width columns

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Layout stuff. */
header {grid-area: h;}
footer {grid-area: f;}
main {grid-area:m;}
.top-level-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "h h h h h"
    ". m m m ."
    "f f f f f";
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr); /* NEW */
}

/* Cosmetics only - you can ignore what's below here. */
header, footer {
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
}

main {
  border: 3px solid red;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-level-wrapper">
  <header>I am a header!</header>
  <main>
    <h3>Some page title</h3>
    <p>
      Some text. And some more, and more, and more, until this paragraph, which really ought to be wrapping, will instead lengthen the main section and break the template's contract.
    </p>
  </main>
  <footer>I am a footer!</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah nice, thank you! For some reason I wrongly recalled it as being an either/or, where the default behavior is equal space. Added a repeat(5, 1fr) and it did the right thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the `grid-template-columns` property:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74wowm1d/)

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Layout stuff. */
header {grid-area: h;}
footer {grid-area: f;}
main {grid-area:m;}
.top-level-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    "h h h h h"
    ". m m m ."
    "f f f f f";
}

/* Cosmetics only - you can ignore what's below here. */
header, footer {
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
}

main {
  border: 3px solid red;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-level-wrapper">
  <header>I am a header!</header>
  <main>
    <h3>Some page title</h3>
    <p>
      Some text. And some more, and more, and more, until this paragraph, which really ought to be wrapping, will instead lengthen the main section and break the template's contract.
    </p>
  </main>
  <footer>I am a footer!</footer>
</div>
```